# Handling two submit buttons in a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, jquery-validate

So I have a pretty long form that a broke up into two piece with a divs. I'm also using jquery's validate plugin. I have a submit button on the first div, when pressed, it validates the form and if successful moves onto the next form. The problem is the form gets confused on what submit button is actually submitting the entire form. Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmuG8/29/)

I was thinking about changing the first submit to a button and make the click event call the validate but that didn't really work. Does anyone know how I can make it so that the submit button on the second page should submit (post) the entire form? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement a multi-part form similar to the ["Buy & Sell a House" demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/) in the [Validation samples](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#A_multipart_.22buy.26sell_a_house.22_form).

> Contributed by Michael Evangelista, showing a multipart form for
>   buying and selling houses.
>
> Notable features of the demo:
>
> Multipart, implemented using the jQuery UI accordion and a custom
>   method to check if an element is on the current page when validated
>   Integration with masked-input plugin, see Phone and Zip fields

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both submit forms will send the same form back to the server. Separating the two using a div doesn't logically separate the form into smaller sub forms.

I would say the simplest solution is to use two separate forms since if you can only use  submit buttons for posting the form to the server.

You could houwever use some jQuery with some javascript which is activated at the press of a button, reads the necessary inputs and sends them to server via jQuery's [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function. I also suggest to look at jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.